# easepick calendar custom localization

Tags: javascript, localization, calendar, translation

I need the calendar to be translated into Macedonian. Currently, the easepick calendar doesn't support Macedonian language, so I need a solution to add a custom translation, if possible. Could you please help me with this issue?

I have tried it this way:

```
const macedonian = {
  months: ["јануари","февруари","март","април","мај","јуни","јули","август", "септември","октомври","ноември","декември"],
  weekday: ["недела","понеделник","вторник","среда","четврток","петок","сабота"],
  weekdaysShort: ["нед","пон","вто","сре","чет","пет","саб"],
  today: "Денес",
  clear: "Избриши",
  titleFormat: "MMMM yyyy"
};

const picker = new easepick.create({
      lang: macedonian,
      ...
});
```

but without success